# Are extensions run first or scripts?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

So, what I'm trying to say is will the extensions you have run before the scripts on the page?

Which one will run first:

extension scripts

or

`<script src="websitescript.js"></script>`

I'm asking because I wanna make an extension that checks the site. (will check if it's secure or not and use other API's)

Comment: It's controlled by [run_at](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you! This was very helpful, if this was an answer I would upvote!